# What is the point of a Type 1 Hypervisor?

Tags: linux, operating-system, virtual-machine, virtualbox, hypervisor

I've been trying to get into Linux lately, and while experimenting with different distros on VirtualBox, I've come across it being a a 'type 2' hypervisor. Now, after a quick search, it became clear what type 1 and type 2 hypervisors are, but my question is, what is the point of using a type 2 hypervisor instead for directly installing the OS?

Everything I had come across seems to focus on comparisons between Type 1 vs Type 2, rather than telling why use Type 1 instead of a direct OS installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A type 1 hypervisor runs directly on the machine without a "host" operating system, such as Linux, running underneath. Thus, since there is no "host" operating system consuming resources, such as compute, memory, and I/O bandwidth, the hypervisor can provide more resources to the virtual machines.

On the other hand, a type 2 hypervisor runs on top of a "host" operating system. This generally makes the type 2 hypervisor easier to install and configure, though the "host" operating system consumes resources that now cannot be provided to the virtual machines.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Not having a host OS, which would consume resources does make sense.. but wouldn't it be easier to just install the distro, without using any hypervisor. Unless of course a type 1 hypervisor make it much more easier to install an OS compared to a direct installation...

Comment: @TharinduDissanayake I assume you're asking why not just install the guest OS directly onto the machine rather than use a hypervisor? A hypervisor generally supports multiple virtual machines at once, so you can run multiple guest operating systems at the same time on the machine with a hypervisor. Furthermore, if you don't trust the guest operating system (such as in a cloud environment), the hypervisor will protect the hardware and other software from the guest (e.g., the hypervisor will ensure the guest can only read/write its own data, rather than arbitrary data, on a hard drive).